# Prepopulate Cloud Page in Salesforce Marketing Cloud from Email with UTM tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am sending an email to subscribers and would like them to click on a button in the email which then takes them to a Cloud page with a Smart Capture form. I would like the Smart Capture form to prepopulate the values of First Name, Last Name, and Email and then have a hidden field that I would like to capture the Contact ID which we use as our subscriber key. All works fine in testing but then when I sent the email, it took the contact to the Cloudpage but did not pull in the values. I determined that is because on a real send our links are appended with UTM parameters. The only way I have figured around this is to turn on "Track Clicks" on the send, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to still track clicks and have the page prepopulate?

**Here's the code for my button and the Ampscript on the page.**

**Button:**

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(CloudPageNumber, 'cid', [Contact ID], 'fname', [First Name], 'lname', [Last Name], 'email', Email)=%%
```

**Ampscript on Page**

```
%%[
%%=RequestParameter('cid')=%%
%%=RequestParameter('fname')=%%
%%=RequestParamenter('lname')=%%
%%=RequestParameter('email')=%%

]%%
```

**Ampscript to pull in First Name Value:**

```
 value="%%=RequestParameter('fname')=%%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don’t have any way to test this now, it should be sufficient to wrap your link in a RedirectTo function:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(CloudPageNumber, 'cid', [Contact ID], 'fname', [First Name], 'lname', [Last Name], 'email', Email))=%%”>click</a>
```

Reference: https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/